# Store function ouput if output isnt false (in a single call)

Tags: python

Is there a way to store the output of the function but only if it isnt false, and not having to call the function 2 times as in the example?

```
def example(x):
    if x>=5:
        return "great"
    else: 
        return False

def main():
    x = 5
    if example(x):
        asnwer = example(x)
    else: 
        print("x<5")

main()
```

Comment: there is no method to do it . Assing it to some variable before `if` and use this variable.

Comment: walrus operator? to assign the value. otherwise you could use a class to keep the value as part of the class, but either way you would have to assign the value to a variable

Answer (score 2):

If your Python interpreter version 3.8 or greater, you can use Assignment Expresions

```
import random


def example():
    return random.randint(0, 10)


if (result := example()) >= 5:
    print(result)
else:
    print("x < 5")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def main():
    x = 5
    result = example(x)
    asnwer = result if result else print("x<5")
```

You could also just modify the function:

```
def example(x):
    return "Great" if x>=5 else print("x<5")

def main():
    x = 5
    asnwer = example(x)

main()
```

This would give `asnwer == None` when `x<5` and `asnwer == Great` when `x>=5`.

Comment: yeah i was looking for some magical one line solution but i guess there isnt, thank you

Comment: I didn't downvote, but... you changed the function dramatically by having it print and return `None`. And its made the function less generic to boot.

Comment: @tdelaney I can see differing opinions with my secondary approach, but originally it was just the first code block when it got downvoted lol

Comment: `asnwer = result if result else print("x<5")` in your first example may not pass a code review. The problem is partly with the original code which doesn't set a value for `asnwer` in the False case. Here, its set to `None`. But one wouldn't generally assign the result of a print (or anything that isn't really returning anything sensible) to a variable. That is just using a side effect of the function.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. If it weren't a one-liner then `asnwer` wouldn't be set at all. Still inevitable that *something* isn't set to `None` or `great`.